# Film with an invisible body hopping spirit which is let loose from watching an old movie tape

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for a horror (family?) film. The story is about a kid accidentally releasing the monster (invisible spirit which can possess people and others) while watching an old movie tape. Along with the monsters there was a cop also coming out from that old movie.  But he was possessed by the spirit first.
After that the spirit moved from body to body (possessing a boy in the end I think), the cop teamed up with the kid and solved the mess.

I watched it online few years ago. And I tried many keywords to search for it, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Hi there! Maybe you'd have some more info to give us, such as when you watched that, when it was likely made? Was the language English, was it a translation?

Comment: This sounds like a mix of "[Last Action Hero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Action_Hero)" and "[The Ring 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ring_Two)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like [*Monster Makers* (2003 TV movie)](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0363827/plotsummary?ref_=m_tt_ov_pl). It starred Linda Blair and Adam Baldwin. Here is the plot summary from IMDb.com:

> This movie is based on Tim Stoker's experience as a monster movie geek. The monsters in an old non released movie come out of the movie and Tim and his friends in the real world and the movie must find a way to stop the monsters. The movie has bullies, geeks, parents, a love intrest, et cetera.

[Here](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0363827/?ref_=rvi_tt) is a link to the IMDb page. If you read the 2nd user review, it describes the sheriff helping to capture the monsters and it also described the body hopping spirit.

> In 1951 filmmaker Dexter Brisbain writes and directs a monster movie called, "Monsters on the Loose." The film was made on a new type of film called Radium Acetate. A group of monsters somehow get out of the film during an electrical storm and terrorize the city. Brisbain is accused of staging the event and is told to never show the film again. Time goes by and the film is in a trunk in the basement only to be found by the son of the now elderly Brisbain's nurse. Recognizing the title as a long-lost film the son decides to show it to a friend on Halloween. As the film is being shown there is an electrical storm and suddenly the sheriff, Manikin (a living manikin), Verman (a wererat who transforms whenever he smells garbage), and a spirit who can take over anyone's body are loosed on the city. Most of the movie has the boy, Tim, and his girlfriend, Tina, chasing around trying to stop the monsters in their attempt to take over the town with the help of the film's sheriff.

Comment: YEAH! This is it!
Thanks a lot! I've been looking for so long. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Denny Glad you've found what you're looking for! Don't forget to mark the answer as correct when you're able by clicking the checkmark icon.